# Insert multiple UIImages into a "container"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uiimageview

I'd like to know if it's possible to insert multiple images into a "container" in objective-c.

For example, if i had an image of a front wheel, a back wheel, and the body of a car. Could i position these all in a container so that when i move or tranform (scale, rotate) the container, all the images inside will perform the that action? At the same time i could have one or more of the images inside the container performing an animation.

I hope that's clear and i've properly explained what i'm trying to do.

Comment: You could simply crate UIView and add UIImageViews to it as subview. Or am i missing something?

Comment: No, I don't believe you are missing anything! I'm still very new to this and didn't even think of this. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. All you need to do is create a UIView that will serve as a container. Then you add your UIImageViews (you can't simply insert UIImage - UIImage has to be in UIImageView) as subviews to your container view using `[view addSubview:];` method.

Comment: Could i create these images using interface builder; set their dimensions and properties in the inspector and add them as subviews in the code? It would save me having to tediously code all the properties of each image.

Comment: You could, but if you're doing it interface builder it would be easier for you to also add them to a UIView in interface builder. You just have to create an extra and big enough UIVIew (in IB) first and then add UIImageViews to it. I'm not at my mac at the moment but if you'll have troubles finding out how to do this i can later make a screenshot of how it should look like.

Comment: Thanks for that, maybe we could take this to chat if you don't mind - i'm having some trouble positioning my `UIView` in IB. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11986/uiview-and-subviews

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about container,
But I have another approach,

Why don't you make one custom view and put all the images inside that, and can perform all the operation over that view,

I am posting some important method, let me know if its works for you, i may share some more detail

```
 -(void)refreshSession{
        // check all the added view, if needs to be displayed, then displayed them. 
        int visibleViews = [self getVisibleViews];

        if(visibleViews ==  0 ){
            // if no more views to be displayed, then then let it not be visible, 
            [[self window] orderOut:self];

            // do it will not be visible to anyone 
            return;
        }

        [self resize:visibleViews];


        int viewsPerSide = [self getViewsPerRow];//ceil(sqrt(count)); 

        int count = [pViewArray count];

        int viewIndex=0;
        NSInteger index = 0;
        NSPoint curPoint = NSZeroPoint;

        // Starting at the bottom left corner
        // we should check all visible views 
        for ( int i = 0; i < count ; i++ ) {

            // it will give only the view that needs to be shown
            NSView *subview = [self getViewAtIndex:i];//(NSView *)[pViewArray objectAtIndex:i];

            // is this visible 
            if(![self isViewVisibleAtIndex:i])
                continue;

            // is view visible 


            // if we have view to display then lets display it. 
            if(subview){
                //[[[self window] contentView]setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
                [[[self window]contentView] addSubview:subview ];
                [self checkMask:viewIndex view:subview];
                viewIndex++;

                // let all the frame have same rect, regardless what are those 
                NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(curPoint.x, curPoint.y, BOXWIDTH, BOXHEIGHT);
                // add them into the subview 
                NSRect newFrame = [self integralRect:frame];
                [subview setFrame:newFrame];
                [[subview animator] setFrame:[self integralRect:frame]];

                [self setSubViewMask:subview ContentView:[[self window]contentView]];

                // Now set the point 
                curPoint.x += BOXWIDTH + SEPARATION;                        // Stack them horizontally
                if ((++index) % viewsPerSide == 0) {                        // And if we have enough on this row, move up to the next
                    curPoint.x = 0;                
                    curPoint.y += BOXHEIGHT + SEPARATION;

                }
            }
        }
        NSArray *pSubViewsArray = [[[self window]contentView]subviews];
        int arrayCount = [pSubViewsArray count];

        debugLog<<"Array Count"<<arrayCount<<endl;

    }
```